# imports not being resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I have newly imported projects, and, after fixing some maven conf issues, main project classes cannot resolve imports, even though they are in place.

Comment: Your source path is not properly set up. Use `src/main/java` as the source path, not just `src`. And, also read [ask] good questions, so that you get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

All your package names are changed to `main.java.packagename` (or atleast eclipse is treating like that) which is the reason for the errors.

Fix your source folder as `src/main/java` instead of just `src`

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh your maven project:
Project=>right click =>maven=> update project.